# Should I down-grade to Drupal 6.x? There seems to be much better support!

Tags: 6

If I'm only looking to throw some easy-to-use modules together for a client and then put the Zen theme on, should I stick to Drupal 6.x? I've noticed in my exploration of Drop-down menus in 7.x that there is very little support for it in the form of modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 6 is certainly an option, and it will likely retain a sizable installed-base for some time to come, until February 24, 2016, the date after which Drupal 6 will not be anymore supported and it will not receive any security fix.

That said, Drupal 7 is where the focus is now; it will continue to be in the future, until November 1, 2023, the date of the Drupal 7 end-of-life, the date after which no security issues will be fixed for Drupal 7.

In my experience, the simple/basic/popular modules are already quite well supported in Drupal 7; only the more "exotic" modules have not been ported to Drupal 7, yet.

I've moved my site to Drupal 7 with relatively few issues; Drupal-7-specific documentation, or the lack of it, can be a challenge.

With regards to drop-down menus, [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) is a Drupal 7 module with releases for Drupal 8 and Drupal 9 too. At least, the [8.x-1.4](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish/releases/8.x-1.4) release is reported to be compatible with both those Drupal releases, but some issues need to still be fixed, to warranty a complete compatibility with Drupal 9 or Drupal 10.